# Who can mark things as community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

What kind of permissions are required to mark another person's questions as community wikis? Is this only available to moderators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740) *(which is the reference to follow, I only copy the current version here, it might not be actual in the coming months)*:

> ### How does a post become a Community Wiki post?
>
> There are several ways a question or
> answer can enter community wiki mode,
> and most of these ways will occur
> automatically based on the rules of
> the system.
>
> Posts enter community wiki mode when:
>
> - The body of the post has been edited six (**6**) times by at least four
>   (**4**) different people.
> - The post has been edited eight (**8**) times by the original owner.
> - The post's author checks the *community wiki* checkbox when composing the question or answer.
>   <sup><sub>Note that this checkbox is
>   only available to users with a
>   reputation of 15 or more.</sub></sup>
> - The post is edited by its original author, who when doing so opts to
>   check the *community wiki*.
> - An answer posted to a Community Wiki question will also be Community Wiki.
>   <sup><sub>Note that when a question is
>   made CW after answers have already
>   been posted, the existing answers are
>   not normally converted to CW
>   automatically.</sub></sup>
> - The question generates more than **30** answers (**15** on Super User). In this case, the question and all
>   answers will enter community mode, as
>   will any future answers.
> - A moderator has reason to believe that the question serves better in
>   community wiki mode.
>
> ** note that the rules outlined
> above are based on observations; the
> actual behavior of SO is subject to
> change without notice, and may well
> have done so since this was last
> updated...*

Comment: +1, much better than my answer :-)

Comment: @Andy - i'm duplicating the FAQ, it's not ideal... But closing directly as duplicate would have been rude, so.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I tried searching, but I didn't find that one. All the questions I found were about the merits of having community wikis, whether they should be renamed, etc.